# Energy Function on Hyperbolic Half Plane - Critical Points?

Tags: functional-analysis, differential-geometry, optimization, calculus-of-variations, euler-lagrange-equation

In this problem we try to find the critical points (ideally minima)
of the energy functional on curves in the hyperbolic plane. Generally, for any
Riemannian manifold (U, g) the energy functional is given by $$E(\gamma) = \frac{1}{2} \int_I g_{\gamma (t)} (\gamma '(t), \gamma '(t))dt$$

for curves γ : I → U.

(i) For the upper half plane model of hyperbolic space **H$^2$ = { z = x+iy $\in$ R; y>0} with riemannian metric** (ds$^2$ = $\frac{dx^{2} + dy^{2}}{y^{2}}$) calculate
the ODE a curve γ : I → H$^2$ has to satisfy in order to be a critical point
of the energy functional under compactly supported variations.

(ii) Recall that SL(2, R) acts by isometries on H$^2$ via
A · z = $\frac
{az + b}
{cz + d}$
for A ∈ SL(2, R). Show that the energy does not change when a curve γ
is moved by an isometry to A · γ.

**For...**

**i)** Would I simply take the Euler Lagrange equations and say that the point, $\gamma$ is a solution to the E-L equations? I'm not sure how to solve this, isn't there only one equation which, when satisfied denotes a critical point? I.e., the Euler-Lagrange Equations?

**ii)** Here I would basically take $\gamma$ and act on it by A so that it'd have $\gamma$ where z is in the definition but idk how exactly to show the energy doesn't change. I'm not sure what form $\gamma$ would even have so I'm not sure I understand how to show this. I know this is basically saying we want to show E($\gamma$) is invariant under multiplication and addition of its solutions but can't quite get started.

Answer (score 1):

First let me answer your second question. By definition isometry $A$ acts on a Riemannian manifold in the following way. Let $p\in M$ and $v,w\in T_pM$ (tangent space of $M$). Then $$g_p(v,w)=g_{A(p)}(D_pA(v),D_pA(w)).$$
Now in $\mathbb{H}^2$ this is equivalent to the fact that $d(z_1,z_2)=d(Az_1,Az_2)$ where $d$ is the hyperbolic distance (one of the way to prove this is to use the explicit formulas of hyperbolic distances between two points). Now use the above formula and chain rule to show that $E(A(\gamma))=E(\gamma)$.

Now coming back to your first question. The main computational difficulty in EL equation is to compute the integrand which is the metric in this case. And so you can choose two paths. One is through crude computation as you have suggested. There is another way from which this whole question is coming from. As a general question this could be asked for any Riemannian manifold and try to get a characterization of the critical points. It turns out that the critical points are exactly the geodesics (modulo some generic conditions on the manifold but you can ignore them in this context). This whole story has a name: *The first variation formula*.

Comment: So what you're saying, if I understand correctly, is that $d(z_{1}, z_{2}) = d(Az_{1}, Az_{2})$ which is the hyperbolic distance between two points (I assume given by an explicit formula one could look up) is equivalent (in the context of the upper half plane) to E($\gamma$) = E(A$\gamma$)?

Also so the first variation formula, in this case, would be the ODE I'd be looking for? As I understand it the first variation formula is used to identify critical points while the second variation formula is used  to characterize those critical points? I

Comment: $d(z_1,z_2)=d(Az_1,Az_2)$ is equivalent to the formula I have written in the first three lines. Using this formula it is straightforward to prove $E(A\gamma)=E(\gamma)$. And you are right. The first variation formula is exactly the EL equation in this context hence is the ODE you are looking for.

Comment: Also, as you have mentioned  first variation formula is used to identify critical points. This is exactly the motivation behind EL equations. Because critical points are local maxima or minima. To find whether it is a maxima or minima you have to check whether the second derivative is positive or negative. That is exactly the second variation formula.

Comment: Oh yes I see that since g is the metric.. I was a little confused as to what the D's were doing in there on the RHS but not the LHS if all thats changing is we're bringing in the isometry. I really appreciate the help you've given me thus far, I'll be posting more parts on this premise (likely with a very similar name) tomorrow afternoon if you're interested in responding to that.